# Doctrine Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created a request to get employees, from site->entreprise... My tables are link as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWWUl.png)
I've maid the following request in doctrine :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->leftJoin('e.entreprise_id', 's')
            ->leftJoin('s.clients', 'c')
            ->andWhere('e.entreprise_id = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult()
        ;
```

But when I try to run the request I have the following error :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 96 near 'entreprise_id': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Can you tell me why

Comment: is entreprise_id an association ?

Comment: Hi tahnks for the answer, Normaly yes according to my Entreprise Entity `/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Site", mappedBy="entreprise_id")
     */
    private $entreprise_id;`

Comment: try to replace 
`->andWhere('e.entreprise_id = :val')` 
with 
`->andWhere('s.id = :val')`

and instead of `->setParameter('val', $value)` 
use `->setParameter('val', $value->getId())`